# Python printing - For loop

Tags: python, formatting

I have this function which is printing out all odd numbers between `1` and `100`. I want a comma `,` between all numbers except the last one `99`

```
for i in range(1,100,2):
    print(str(i), end=',')
```

What I got:

> 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 ... 97, 99,

What I want:

> 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 ... 97, 99

Comment: Also, `print(*range(1, 100, 2), sep=', ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string = ""

for i in range(100):

```
if i == 99:

    string = string + str(i)

else:

    string = string + str(i) + ","
```

print string

Comment: Yes but i want all the numbers on the same row.
Like --> 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15 ... 97, 99

Comment: i edit it.... sorry I had problems with the site... it works?

Comment: Yes, it works and i can understand what you did! Thanks!

Comment: :) have a great day!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to inject delimiters between values, which you can create using a generator expression as follows

```
>>> ', '.join(str(i) for i in range(1,100,2))
'1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59, 61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79, 81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99'
```

Comment: Nice thanks!
I was looking for a way to do it like this (see below) but it doesnt work.
Dont Think i understand it.

for i in range(1,100,2):
    print(', '.join(str(i))